# Python / MySQL : Programming error 1146 - Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, homebrew, spyder

My goal is to create a database which includes tables (and entries) describing containing information about S&P 500 constituents.

1) I have installed MySQL using homebrew, created a database and a table named 'securities_master'

[image: Terminal screen grab]

2) I open spyder and enter the following

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# insert_symbols.py
"""
Created on Fri Jan 13 17:42:53 2017

@author: 
"""



from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
from math import ceil
import bs4
import MySQLdb as mdb
import requests


def obtain_parse_wiki_snp500():
"""
Download and parse the Wikipedia list of S&P500 
constituents using requests and BeautifulSoup.

Returns a list of tuples for to add to MySQL.
"""
# Stores the current time, for the created_at record
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

# Use requests and BeautifulSoup to download the 
# list of S&P500 companies and obtain the symbol table
response = requests.get(
    "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)

# This selects the first table, using CSS Selector syntax
# and then ignores the header row ([1:])
symbolslist = soup.select('table')[0].select('tr')[1:]

# Obtain the symbol information for each 
# row in the S&P500 constituent table
symbols = []
for i, symbol in enumerate(symbolslist):
    tds = symbol.select('td')
    symbols.append(
        (
            tds[0].select('a')[0].text,  # Ticker
            'stock', 
            tds[1].select('a')[0].text,  # Name
            tds[3].text,  # Sector
            'USD', now, now
        ) 
    )
return symbols


def insert_snp500_symbols(symbols):
"""
Insert the S&P500 symbols into the MySQL database.
"""
# Connect to the MySQL instance
db_host = 'localhost'
db_user = 'root'
db_pass = ''
db_name = 'securities_master'
con = mdb.connect(
    host=db_host, user=db_user, passwd=db_pass, db=db_name
)

# Create the insert strings
column_str = """ticker, instrument, name, sector, 
             currency, created_date, last_updated_date
             """
insert_str = ("%s, " * 7)[:-2]
final_str = "INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
    (column_str, insert_str)

# Using the MySQL connection, carry out 
# an INSERT INTO for every symbol
with con: 
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)


if __name__ == "__main__":
symbols = obtain_parse_wiki_snp500()
insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)
print("%s symbols were successfully added." % len(symbols))
```

3) The above is copied verbatim from the book and is supposed to populate the 'symbol' table in 'securities_master' however as you can see it returns an error...

```
in [2]: runfile('/Users/alexfawzi/untitled4.py',           wdir='/Users/alexfawzi')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-2-ecff2c9aa5ce>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/alexfawzi/untitled4.py', wdir='/Users/alexfawzi')

File "/Users/alexfawzi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/alexfawzi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

File "/Users/alexfawzi/untitled4.py", line 92, in <module>
insert_snp500_symbols(symbols)

File "/Users/alexfawzi/untitled4.py", line 87, in insert_snp500_symbols
cur.executemany(final_str, symbols)

File "/Users/alexfawzi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 253, in executemany
r = self._query('\n'.join([query[:p], ',\n'.join(q), query[e:]]))

File "/Users/alexfawzi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 346, in _query
rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/Users/alexfawzi/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 310, in _do_query
db.query(q)

ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'securities_master.symbol' doesn't exist")
```

Programming error! Dang! I can't imagine it's fun picking through noobs' errors so thank you very much to anyone who does take the time to help.

Comment: you should first run this program manually line by line on python interpreter to have an idea of whats going on , make sure the web url is feteched successfully

Comment: Thanks for the help, I changed to using SQLite and then went through/changed it line by line alongside a tutorial and it's not only working but I actually understand what I'm looking at now. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `SHOW TABLES;` shows the `‘` and `’` quote marks (a.k.a 'curly' quotes), instead of... well... nothing. The result of that query should show table names without quotes at all, which means that you've accidentally *created* the table with 'curly' quotes.

For example:

[image: show tables example]

Your options are to change the code like this:

```
final_str = "INSERT INTO `‘symbol’` (%s) VALUES (%s)"
```

Or recreate the table without the quote marks.

Do the second one.

I'm guessing that you originally copied the table name from a website or a document, which would explain why it would have 'curly' quotes instead of 'straight' quotes (`'`). Straight quotes imply strings in most programming languages, but curly quotes aren't actually used in programming - they're substituted in text by word processors and WYSIWYG editors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating everything with these ticks ‘ try backticks `

Change final_str to this:

```
final_str = "INSERT INTO symbol (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (column_str, insert_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

securities_master.symbol actually doesn't exist. I know which code you're using and if you copy the mysql statements straight out of the pdf it puts the ‘ symbol into your database names.

Example: table name ‘symbols‘ is not the same as symbols

Change the mysql statement to this correct statement (and all the table statements)

```
CREATE TABLE symbol ( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, exchange_id int NULL,
ticker varchar(32) NOT NULL,
instrument varchar(64) NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NULL,
sector varchar(255) NULL,
currency varchar(32) NULL, created_date datetime NOT NULL, last_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY index_exchange_id (exchange_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4;
```

not

```
CREATE TABLE ‘symbol‘ ( ‘id‘ int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ‘exchange_id‘ int NULL,
‘ticker‘ varchar(32) NOT NULL,
‘instrument‘ varchar(64) NOT NULL,
‘name‘ varchar(255) NULL,
‘sector‘ varchar(255) NULL,
‘currency‘ varchar(32) NULL, ‘created_date‘ datetime NOT NULL, ‘last_updated_date‘ datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (‘id‘), KEY ‘index_exchange_id‘ (‘exchange_id‘) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

See the difference in the two statements with the ‘ symbol.

Create both tables and then check the differences between the names if you cant see it I missed it for a while too.

Also you don't need the '' symbols around the names, you can just put the names in like I did in the first and correct mysql statement.